# Dar click en boton de pagina web, existen 2 con el mismo ID

Tags: vba

Me podrían apoyar, estoy elaborando una macro en `VBA` y necesito dar `click` en el botón *CONFIRMAR*. El problema esta en que existen 2 botones con el mismo `ID` y sinceramente no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Adjunto el `HTML`:

```
<div class="btn" id="botonesDiv">
    <a class="button" id="btnCont" onclick="javascript: regresarListado();" href="javascript: void(0)">
        <span>CANCELAR</span>
    </a>
    <a class="button" id="btnCont" onclick="javascript: capturaCorreoContratacion();" href="javascript: void(0)">
        <span>CONFIRMAR</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usar un css [selector de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick*='Contratacion']").click
```

- Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr tenga un valor que contenga (*) value.

Comment: Excelente, me ayudo mucho amigo, gracias!!